# c# TcpClient: проблема разрыва соединения

Tags: c#, tcp

Доброго времени суток. Пишу класс Tcp клиента. Есть проблема закрытия соединения с сервером. При попытке разорвать соединение с серверной стороны клиент попросту никак не реагирует(хотя до недавних пор работало).
При попытке разорвать соединение со стороны клиента - программа зависает на методе отключения (цикл проверки соединения)
Код проверки наличия входящих данных и статуса подключения (отдельный поток):

```
void waitData()
{
    try
    {

        while ( flagNeedDisconnect==false && verifyConnected())//flagNeedDisconnect - флаг необходимости отключиться
        {

            if (CLNT_STREAM.CanRead && CLIENT.Available>0)
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[CLIENT.ReceiveBufferSize];
                CLNT_STREAM.Read(data, 0, data.Length);


                if (NewData != null)
                {
                    TCPClientNewDataEventArgs e = new TCPClientNewDataEventArgs(data);
                    object[] prms = { this, e };
                    if (formInvoke != null)
                        formInvoke.Invoke(NewData, prms);
                    else
                        NewData(this, e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    closeSocket();
}
```

Код проверки соединения:

```
bool verifyConnected()
{
    try
    {
        if (isConnected && CLIENT.Connected)//isConnected - флаг устанавливаемый вручную
        {
            if ((CLIENT.Client.Poll(0, SelectMode.SelectWrite)) && (!CLIENT.Client.Poll(0, SelectMode.SelectError)))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
                if (CLIENT.Client.Receive(buffer, SocketFlags.Peek) == 0)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
            resetConnect(true,e.ToString());
            return false;
    }

}
```

Код метода отключения

```
public void disconnect()
{
    flagNeedDisconnect = true;
    CLIENT.Close();
    while (CLIENT != null)
    {
    }
    flagNeedDisconnect = false;
}
public void closeSocket()
{
    int result = 0;

    if (CLNT_STREAM != null)
    {
        CLNT_STREAM.Close();
        CLNT_STREAM = null;
        result++;
    }

    if (CLIENT != null)
    {
        //CLIENT.Client.Disconnect(true);
        CLIENT.Close();
        CLIENT = null;
        result++;
    }

    resetConnect(false, "close socket");

}
```

Я предполагаю, что проблема заключается в потоке ожидания входящих данных. Логика здесь такая, что при установке флага `flagNeedDisconnect` как `true` или потери подключения - цикл завершится и сокет закроется. Но происходит следующее - я пытаюсь отключиться с клиентской стороны, сервер начинает жрать 100 процентов цп (используется сторонняя библиотека для сервера,такое происходит когда клиент отключается, но сервер на это не реагирует), а сам клиент на долгое время зависает.Если в метод  `disconnect` добавить `CLIENT = null;`, то поток отреагирует лишь через время, и проверка подключение выдаст ожидаемое исключение.

Comment: Могу предположить, что нужно делать через поток.

Comment: Отключаться через поток? Я назначаю ему флаг, который он считывает. Просто дело в том что теперь он зависает.

Comment: Зачем получение данных так сложно написано? Почему нельзя было просто вызвать `Receive`?

Comment: Я третий день изучаю c#. Не знаю о таком подходе.

Comment: @Матвей о каком "подходе" идет речь? Это ж просто здравый смысл. Чтобы получить данные - надо вызвать метод получения данных!

Comment: 3 день, зачем сразу ринулись писать серверные приложения, не изучив как устроено? Советую изучить многопоточные приложения, а также изучить криптографические алгоритмы, подобные RSA.

Comment: Я все таки продолжу ждать совета по делу, а не жизненных наставлений. Вопрос стоит в отключении, а не в тотальной организации многопоточных приложений.
-----------
По поводу получения данных - именно подобный подход был описан на многих ресурсах (в тч хабр).

Comment: *"Зачем получение данных так сложно написано? Почему нельзя было просто вызвать Receive?"* - это и был совет по делу. В одной строке сложнее допустить ошибку, чем в сотне.

Comment: Кстати, если не сложно - приведите источники, где учат писать код так как написали вы.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, насчет совета по делу (а именно зависание потока, а не изучение криптографии) комментарий был адресован другому. Статьи в "интернетах" говорят, что для получения входных данных от сервера нужно узнать есть ли эти данные либо (и, либо) узнать размер входных данных. При их наличии выполнить получение. 
Вы все говорите про receive - приведите пример работы с методом вместо развода холивара. Скорее всего я плохо искал, ибо ничего толкового нашел.

Comment: P.S.: Зависание и все прочее я уже исправил сам. Но тем не менее интересен Ваш вариант. Мой вариант заключается в тройке строк. Все остальное нужно для проверки соединения (которое я так же уже переписал)